# Arduino motor driver 3.7v

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I am planning to build my own micro quadcopter, so I bought an Arduino 101 and 3.7v [micro DC motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/8pcs-DC3-7-4-2V-716-7-16-5MM-Micro-DIY-Helicopter-Coreless-DC-Motor-With/32428628283.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.HejABq&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10068_10150_10136_10137_10138_10060_10062_10141_10056_10055_10054_10059_123_10099_10103_10102_10096_10148_10147_10052_10053_10050_10107_10142_10051_10143_10084_10083_10119_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10078_10079_10073_10070_10123_10120_10124-10119,searchweb201603_1,afswitch_1_afChannel,ppcSwitch_5&btsid=6b1572fc-994b-4376-9bfe-b790f4995472&algo_expid=28d1398b-094f-4b9b-8232-734ed5585b4d-0&algo_pvid=28d1398b-094f-4b9b-8232-734ed5585b4d).

So the next step is finding a motor driver that can control these four motors, using PWM pins on the Arduino board. I spent a lot of time searching for it, but all I found was a 5v motor driver and other types of Arduino shields that can't work in my project. Has anyone my requirement (name of motor drive, micro-controller, circuit)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build your own H bridge with suitable MOSFETs?

Comment: Majenko do you have any pdf about the circuit and the element that i need , because i'm still a student so i know a little bit about electronic components .Thanks !

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=h-bridge+mosfet&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7sdaU55fTAhXIvBoKHRnQDcEQ_AUICCgB&biw=1120&bih=619

Comment: @Majenko He doesn't need a H bridge unless he wants to fly the quad upside down (would be cool to make your quad flip and stay flipped :D ). All he needs are some big logic-level N-channel mosfets. For the components you can easily find information on google about how to connect them, just search for "arduino mosfet motor control", but make sure your mosfets are logic level (it's a must, these motors can draw some amps and you don't want your fets to catch on fire because of them not being fully switched).

Comment: @AndreiDragan That is very true. Imagine the acrobatics you could do though :)